# What does theoretical mean in qqplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have been reading about `qqplot` and do not understand what does theoretical mean when plotting a graph such as :

```
ggplot(mtcars) +
   stat_qq(aes(sample = mpg))
```

[image]

In the above plot, what does theoretical mean?

Comment: Try reading a few posts over at Cross Validated as well. Like this one: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/101274/how-to-interpret-a-qq-plot

Comment: Why did you make this plot? What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you know what your QQplot is describing? quantile-quantile plots compare a theoretical distribution of data points (such as a normal distribution) with the real data to determine if these data match the presumed distribution.

http://data.library.virginia.edu/understanding-q-q-plots/

Understanding Q-Q Plots

The Q-Q plot, or quantile-quantile plot, is a graphical tool to help us assess if a set of data plausibly came from some theoretical distribution such as a Normal or exponential. For example, if we run a statistical analysis that assumes our dependent variable is Normally distributed, we can use a Normal Q-Q plot to check that assumption. It’s just a visual check, not an air-tight proof, so it is somewhat subjective. But it allows us to see at-a-glance if our assumption is plausible, and if not, how the assumption is violated and what data points contribute to the violation.

A Q-Q plot is a scatterplot created by plotting two sets of quantiles against one another. If both sets of quantiles came from the same distribution, we should see the points forming a line that’s roughly straight.

OP asked about the values of the X axis and their meaning. See here for more information about Normal distributions and their axes:
https://www.mathsisfun.com/data/standard-normal-distribution.html

Comment: _"quantile-quantile plots compare a theoretical distribution of data points (such as a normal distribution) with the real data to determine if these data match the presumed distribution."_ What is a presumed distribution?

Comment: Sorry if the vocabulary could be more simple:
If I think my data is normally distributed, I am PRESUMING it is a normal distribution.

pre·sume (prəˈz(y)o͞om/)
verb: presume; 3rd person present: presumes; past tense: presumed; past participle: presumed; gerund or present participle: presuming

1.  To suppose that something is the case on the basis of probability.
    "I presumed that the man had been escorted from the building"
    synonyms:assume, suppose, dare say, imagine, take it, expect, believe, think,

Comment: How are the values of x-axis computed? What does it mean? How does it matter?

Comment: It's not up to stackoverflow to explain the bases of your experiments, but here goes: The values of the X axis are representative of the presumed distribution. I'll continue with my Normal distribution example:
In a normal distribution, the mean is centered between standard deviations. Therefore, in your plot -2 represents values in the dataset that fall 2 standard deviations lower than the mean. The reciprocal is true as well: +2 represents samples that fall 2 standard deviations above the mean. I hope this helps and please upvote if this answers your question :)